# Store array into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database can record which user apply the course

the apply table like this

```
id  post_id user_id
1   3   56
2   2   33
3   3   78
4   3   99
```

however I am thinking to change user user_id into one string and explode into array.
so instead have many rows in database, one post_id will have only one row.

```
id  post_id user_id
1   3   56,78.99
2   2   33
```

than I use array_diff to delete or update the user_id

and implode it back to string and update it into mySQL.

So 1 post only occupied 1 row instead hundreds of rows. Is this good to do this?

Comment: dont even think about it. trying to go green and save you harddrive some space? try to get to your data later

Comment: It's so wrong way of thinking. Use where clause to find users you are interested in or WHERE IN()

Comment: Has been asked a hundred times in diverse colors before. If you really  ask that yourself, do some research. - See the related column on the right.

Comment: short answer: no, you've got it completely wrong. Your existing table is the better way to do it. Look up [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not. It makes *querying* the database very hard. Try to formulate a query that finds all posts by user `56` to see what I mean.

Keep your database [*normalized*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the way it already is.

- That is, unless you have a **very good reason to denormalize.** (See [@hakre's comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648826/store-array-into-database#comment23946409_16648859))

Comment: so if i have 7 thousand of posts and each post have 300 ppl apply, that will become 7000x300 rows, will this slow the query?

Comment: If you set the indexes right, not really.

Comment: @user Not if your database is properly *indexed*.

Comment: man David rang the cash register on that one !

Comment: De-normalization can actually make sense for performance reasons and indexes can stand in your way. There is no right or wrong, but you should know both concepts and how you can metric so you can decide when you need to switch from one concept to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea, databases are designed to store information as you first describe. If you collapse records you save almost nothing (storage space is generally cheap) and loose the ability to perform usefull queries (performance and convenience) on your data.